# Convergence of $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n) J_0(2n)$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and $J_0(y)$ the Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Let for integers $n\geq 1$ the Möbius function $\mu(n)$, see its definition from this [MathWorld.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html) And here $J_0(y)$ denotes the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero, see this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

> **Question.** What work can be done with the purpose to study if the series
>   $$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n) J_0(2n)$$
>   is convergent? **Many thanks.**

I don't know if our series is convergent. Using [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) one can to see that some partial sums, like next, of our series seem small in absolute value but erratic

`sum mu(n)BesselJ(0,2n), from n=1 to 1000`

`sum mu(n)BesselJ(0,2n), from n=1 to 3000`

Comment: First things first: are you able to prove that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ is divergent? That is not trivial, and it deserves to be investigated *before* moving to more involved series.

Comment: No, I am not able to prove it. You're right and I believe that you advised me this way previously (study/know standard series before different of these). Thus thank you very much for your patience and attention @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but just a direction.

Using the large argument asymptotic for $J_0$ in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), we have
$$
J_0(2n)=\sqrt{\frac1{\pi n}}\cos\left(2n-\frac{\pi}4\right)+O\left(\frac1{n\sqrt n}\right).
$$
The sum of error term is absolutely convergent, so we now consider the convergence of 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\cos\left(2n-\frac{\pi}4\right).
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your remarks in this nice answer.

Comment: Thoughts after this one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164874/is-it-possible-to-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mun-sqrtn-diverg?noredirect=1&lq=1, I conjecture that it is divergent too.

Comment: Yes I know this post and the great answer, the problem is that I don't understand very well due my current knowedges. Many thanks any case, for your conjecture.